# Class view returns object has no attribute 'rindex' error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to rewrite my `function based view` to `class based view`. It raises this error:

```
.../test/User1
```

> 'UserDetailView' object has no attribute 'rindex'

The problem is probably obvious, I'm new in `class based views`.

So what to do to be able get any profile using url `.../test/username`?

My new view:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
```

URLS.PY:

```
url(r'^test/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetailView(),name="user_detail"),
```

And template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{{ userprofile.as_p }}
{% endblock %}
```

My old view is this:

```
def get_user_profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    jobs = user.jobs.all()
    table = MyJobsTable(jobs)

    context = {
        'my_jobs': table,
        "user": user
    }
    return render(request, 'auth/profiles/my-profile.html', context=context)
```

And HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h3>{% if user.userprofile.is_translator %} Prekladateľský účet: {% else %} Štandardný
            účet: {% endif %}{{ user.username }} </h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Username: {{ user.username }}</li>
            <li>First name: {{ user.first_name }}</li>
            <li>Last name: {{ user.last_name }}</li>
            <li>Email: {{ user.email }}</li>
            <li>Telephone: {{ user.userprofile.telephone }}</li>
            <li>Languages: {{ user.userprofile.languages.as_p }}</li>
            {#            TODO: DOPLNIT ATRIBUTY + ked je aj translator#}
        </ul>
        {% if user.jobs %}
            <p>My Jobs</p>
            {% render_table my_jobs %}
        {% else %}
            <p>You have no jobs</p>
        {% endif %}
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/edit-profile" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit Your Profile</button>
        </form>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/register-as-translator" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Become A Translator</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.get_user_profile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your urls.py. With a class-based view, you always need to use the [`as_view` classmethod](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf):

```
url(r'^test/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name="user_detail"),
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but it raises now another error: Generic detail view UserDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug. I suppose that I can't use username, but how to use a slug? Or is that different problem?

Comment: You should set `slug_field = 'username'` and `slug_url_kwarg = 'username'` in your class definition. And note that your `get_object` method is broken, but also pointless; you should delete it.